# The most appropriate term for a noisy machine

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests

I've written the following sentence:

> He had wanted to write a letter to Jimmy, an old comrade of his, but when the boisterous clipper started, he decided to have a second breakfast instead whilst waiting for the workers to finish their task.

Someone mentioned that `boisterous` may not fit in here and proposed `clamorous` instead.

How do these words differ from each other, regarding their connotations and are there any more, even better suitable terms to use?

Update:

What about `uproarious`? Can this be used with nonsentient things?

Comment: you might go with something like:  "*... but when the **horrendous** clipper started, he decided ... whilst waiting for the workers to finish their **noisy** task.*"

Comment: What's wrong with *noisy*? *Noisy* is quite a romantic word too, no?

Comment: I would just say "noisy".  Unless it's really loud, in which case it's "deafening".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest word to use here is **"noisy"** or **"loud"**.  Of course, you can use one of the other longer words too, just depends on your target audience.  If the clipper is very loud, you can also use "**deafening**".

On a side note, I personally see nothing wrong with using "boisterous" either.  Personalizing the clipper and giving it an identity is not unusual. Ships are given names, often the name of a lady.  If the lady is boisterous, that gives life to the ship's identity.  Poetic license is expected in literature.  Unless you are writing a technical manual, don't be so sensitive to retentive critics.  The masters often use words in unexpected ways to give their work a life of their own.

Comment: This one is great! I have no idea why I didn't come up with it. Thank you!

Comment: @Sprottenwels I am happy to be of service.

Comment: I think you are right, regarding your side note and sometimes it bothers me indeed. Unfortunately, I havent done much english writing yet and have to rely somewhat on my readers suggestions, for I don't know when something is just plain wrong. I'm very glad you told me about your perception of 'boisterous' here, as I found it when I was searching for a word that described something awfully loud.

Comment: That you can use human adjectives to describe non-sentient beings in narration does not mean you ought to. In this case, it does not seem to add anything plausible in descriptive or metaphorical value, and would probably strike most readers as simply poor usage. (also, does "clipper" actually refer to the type of ship here? I read it as referring to the tool)

Comment: Even the ship seemed sad and lonely.  Her creaks and moans could be heard, as if mourning the loss of her crew.

Comment: @Yang  without seeing the full context of your story it is hard to give you a correct suggestion about that.  Probably better to play it safe and not use it.  But my point is that it can be used under the right context.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Yang about both your words being sentient-agent only.

I think the word you want is **"cacophonous"**. Greek for an 'orrible noise.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I didn'nt know that term and looked it up. Unfortunately, it seems to emphasize dissonance rather than loudness. While this is not bad to describe the clipper, it is necessary to make sure the reader understands it's noisiness.

Answer (score 1):

*Boisterous* and *clamorous* are generally used to describe *sentient* beings, especially groups of sentient beings. The former has connotations of roughness and aggression, and the latter specifically involves *clamors*, or shouts.

*Rackety* and the less common *clangorous* are both more fitting in this context.

Comment: Thank you for your thoughts and explanations. Doesn't `rackety` possess a connotation of joy? I've always thought so.

Comment: @Sprottenwels: If I were watching a movie, the "rackety" machine is the one that brings you joy to look at. In that sense, it does carry a connotation of joy. But in real life, rackety just means it's either shoddily built, or built without regard for noisiness. Doesn't carry the same connotation of joy if it wakes you up every morning.